# How to have multiple command text in SSIS c#

Tags: c#, ssis

Initially I had commandtext defined in my ssis C# script task which counted the number of rows from table A. Now I need to add two more commandtext which counts the rows from table b and C respectively as I need to include the output of that query in my customized email.

```
try
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            if (dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                OleDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
                dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                dbCommand.CommandText = "select count(*) as Total_Source from [dbo].A";
                dbCommand.CommandText = "select count(*) as Total_Destination from [dbo].B";
                dbCommand.CommandText = "select count(*) as Total_Blank from [dbo].C where ColumnA = ''";
                OleDbDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (dbReader.HasRows)
                    dtResults.Load(dbReader);

                string theSum = dtResults.Rows[0]["Total_Source"].ToString();
                string theSum1 = dtResults.Rows[0]["Total_Destination"].ToString();
                //string theSum2 = dtResults.Rows[0]["Count_Blank"].ToString();
```

I believe I need to define command text for table B and C (which is incorrect in the above script) but I am unaware how to do.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Store the counts in variables and return those in a select - make this your SQL statement:

```
DECLARE @total_Source AS INT;
DECLARE @total_Destination AS INT;
DECLARE @total_Blank AS INT;
SELECT @total_Source=Count(*) FROM [dbo].A;
SELECT @total_Destination=Count(*) FROM [dbo].B;
SELECT @total_Blank=Count(*) FROM [dbo].C WHERE ColumnA = ''";
SELECT @total_Source AS Total_Source, @total_Destination AS Total_Destination, @total_Blank AS Total_Blank
```

Comment: Also what @Eliasib13 said, you're overwriting your CommandText. I didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I think that if `CommandText` is a `string` property, you are overwritting it on each sentence you use the `=` operator.

You could try this:

```
//...

OleDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append("select count(*) as Total_Source from [dbo].A;"); // Notice semicolon at the end of the string.
sb.Append("select count(*) as Total_Destination from [dbo].B;");
sb.Append("select count(*) as Total_Blank from [dbo].C where ColumnA = '';");
dbCommand.CommandText = sb.ToString();
OleDbDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

//...
```

Comment: I think the return value is overwritten by the result of previous query, you need to separate each query and execute separately